# Tomcat - Database connection pool issue

Tags: java, xml, tomcat, jdbc, context.xml

Precondition: hostB is not connectable

When using context.xml(A), each data connection is checked upon Tomcat's start-up(throwing errors upon the initialization of data connection pool for hostB), whereas with context.xml(B), it seems nothing is checked with no database connection errors.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Thanks

↓context.xml(A)

```
<Resource name="jdbc/AAA" 
                  initialSize="8"
                  minIdle="8"
                  maxWait="300000"
                  removeAbandoned="true"
                  removeAbandonedTimeout="60"
                  auth="Container" 
                  type="javax.sql.DataSource"
                  username="uname"
                  password="password"
                  driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
                  url="jdbc:sqlserver://hostA:port;databaseName=sqlserverDB" />

 <Resource name="jdbc/BBB" 
                  initialSize="8"
                  minIdle="8"
                  maxWait="300000"
                  removeAbandoned="true"
                  removeAbandonedTimeout="60"
                  auth="Container" 
                  type="javax.sql.DataSource"
                  username="uname"
                  password="password"
                  driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
                  url="jdbc:sqlserver://hostB:port;databaseName=sqlserverDB" />
```

↓context.xml(B)

```
<Resource name="jdbc/AAA" 
                  auth="Container" 
                  type="javax.sql.DataSource"
                  username="uname"
                  password="password"
                  driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
                  url="jdbc:sqlserver://hostA:port;databaseName=sqlserverDB" />

 <Resource name="jdbc/BBB" 
                  auth="Container" 
                  type="javax.sql.DataSource"
                  username="uname"
                  password="password"
                  driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
                  url="jdbc:sqlserver://hostB:port;databaseName=sqlserverDB" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First one has initilsize set and minIdle, so tomcat will try to open 8 connections upon initlization. The second one sits idle till it is actually needed.

Comment: According to [link](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html), by defalut, DBCP creates 10 connections when the pool is started.
Is there any difference between explicitly defining the "initialSize" attribute and implicitly using the default value?

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention the minIdle as well, and this is the main reason in your case. The initialSize used to be 0 by defualt.

Comment: Based on my observation, whether or not the minIdle is set, as long as the initialSize is set to 0, tomcat will not try to open db connections.
DBCP: default initialSize  = 0
Tomcat JDBC: default initialSize  = 10